# 2D game engine for UI - suggestion needed

Tags: 2d, gui

I am planning on making a simple real-time strategy game from the series Stargate Universe. For those who don't know, in the series' center is a spaceship called Destiny. It has a nice control room, with a control interface, what has a holographic control screen. The game basically would run on this. That's what I want to do, easily.

Can you suggest me ANY free 2D engine, what has:
- A top-view area for combat and ship management

- Many UI elements what can be used easily
- a top-on GUI part, where the actual GUI can be put
- a nice GUI for putting all together (a game development framework or workbench)

And written in:

- C#
- ActionScript (Flash)

It is a bit reverse-like, as at the bottom of the layers would be the UI, over it the buttons, and over them would be the actual playground (battlefields, ship elements, etc).

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are already some similar questions to this. I'll just point you to them.

[recommend-a-game-engine-with-2d-gui-for-a-ui-intensive-strategy-game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/recommend-a-game-engine-with-2d-gui-for-a-ui-intensive-strategy-game)

[recommended-2d-game-engine-for-prototyping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/536/recommended-2d-game-engine-for-prototyping)