# Language & framework for fast prototyping Box2d problems

Tags: box2d, prototyping

I am often in need of a fast prototype box2d scene where I can play with parameters. I work with AndEngine on Android which doesn't suit me for prototyping. It's good for the final game, but prototyping is slow.

My requirements are:

- Java or language similar to Java (C-like syntax with garbage collection), scripting languages are fine, but something with fast learning curve (Javascript maybe?). I know Java, Groovy and some remnants of JavaScript and C/C++ from the past, but learning a new language is good.
- Easy to use 2D framework. Must have boxes, circles, polygons and GUI elements like buttons and sliders, everything else is optional.
- Same physics eengine capabilities - maybe there is some HTML5 sandbox that will allow me to do this in browser, but then I need the same performace (like setting fixed step of the box2d engine) as in the phone and I want to see same results.
- Good IDE - currently I use eclipse, so eclipse would be an advantage
- doesn't need to be multiplatform, but must run on Windows
- Would be great if I could change code -> recompile -> see the results immediately (not the case in Java on Android :))

[I like the Flash version of Box2d prototype from here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/28/simulate-radial-gravity-also-know-as-planet-gravity-with-box2d-as-seen-on-angry-birds-space/), but I have no experience with ActionScript, Flash Frameworks, IDEs for it nor the Box2d version ported to Flash.

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. They're not a good fit for the Q/A format. There's [a nice list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines), where you may find something that meets your requirements. You may also find something to use from [this similar question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/536/recommended-2d-game-engine-for-prototyping?rq=1). Good luck.

Comment: If you need to prototype performance, shouldn't you be using the engine you plan on shipping with?

Comment: @Tetrad yes, in the end yes. But in the beginning when I want to prototype something completely new, I just make the scene very quickly to test ideas. When I have the idea I want with the paramteres I want, then I start caring about performance. I was more thinking that browser based sandbox might be limiting the steps of the physics engine - it is not clear from my question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGDX has a pretty decent implementation of Box2D. Its Java and even has a project creator to set up stuff for Eclipse. Its not an active editor, but its copy and paste. Its made for iOS and Android development, but it also compiles to desktop so iteration is much faster.

Most info:
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/PhysicsBox2D